# Nohup does not work with bash for loop properly

Tags: linux, bash, unix, nohup

I have been trying to use nohup with bash for loop and I came across this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099092/why-cant-i-use-unix-nohup-with-bash-for-loop) which was helpful and gave me an idea but my command is still not working properly. What I have right now looks like:

```
nohup sh -c 'for i in {0..9}; do spark-submit --class some.Code /some/Jar.jar --input_path /some/path/part-001"$i"* > test_log.log; done' &
```

when I run this the job fails with the following exception that the input path does not exists and shows me the path as:

```
/some/path/part-001{0..9}*
```

How can I get this to replace `$i` with the actual value of i and not the string `{0..9}`?

Comment: “…nohup with bash…” but your using `nohup sh` which is the basic shell. You need to use `nohup bash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with `nohup`.

Brace expansion [is a bashism](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192480/108618). Your code runs `sh` which does not expand `{0..9}`. Use `bash` instead of `sh`.

If you still want to use `sh`, then `for i in $(seq 0 9); do …`.
<sub>(Almost always one should double-quote `$()`, but in this case not quoting is the right thing.)</sub>